# Left function lost format vba codes

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to split data into multiple worksheets but when I run my codes, it seems like it has lost its format. The list contains parent codes of the products I am based on splitting.

Product code has 0000-00-00 format and parent code is the first 4 digits, 0000. i.e. 0008-99-99 as product code and 0008 as parent code.

So in my result page, I m getting 8 as result not 0008, and that is why I can't get any product details in them. I tried to use left function and it is still giving me 8 not 0008 for instance. I need help with `Sheets(n).Range("A1") = ws3.Cells(i, 1).Text` this line of code. When I run my codes, no error just not populating results.

```
Option Explicit
Sub monthly()


Dim y1 As Workbook
Dim ws1, ws2, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim LR1, LR2, LR3, last As Long
Dim o, r, p As Long


Set y1 = Workbooks("Monthly Template.xlsm")


Set ws2 = y1.Sheets("Products")
Set ws3 = y1.Sheets("List")



LR2 = ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ws3.Activate

With ws3
Range("A1:A32").Sort key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending
End With





LR1 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row



For o = 3 To LR1
ws2.Cells(o, 29).FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-21],4)"
Next o



Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, m As Long, n As String

With Sheets("List")
    j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Sheets("Products")
    l = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

For i = 1 To j
    n = Sheets("List").Cells(i, 1).Text
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = n
    Sheets(n).Range("A1") = ws3.Cells(i, 1).Text
    For k = 3 To l

         With Sheets(n)
           If Sheets(n).Cells(1, 1).Value = Sheets("Products").Cells(k, 29).Value Then

             m = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            .Rows(m + 1).Value = Sheets("Products").Rows(k).Value
            End If

                    End With
                           Next k
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Prepend an apostrophe, or format the cell as text before you write to it. Otherwise if it looks like a number, works like a number, and can be used as a number, as far as Excel is concerned, *it's a number*. Or, keep it as a number, and give the cells a `NumberFormat` such as `0000`.

Comment: Well I can't. Since my vba codes create these sheets on the fly, I don't create them, vba codes do, based on how many parent codes I have in the list. If you see the values in the list, they are already formatted. It is weird that tab name is produced correctly but not Range("A1"). That's why I need help from. I already use `.text`

Comment: It's not weird at all, it's expected behavior - a sheet name is a `String`, a numeric-compatible cell value is a `Double`. Type `0001` in any cell with a `(General)` number format, on any sheet you want - Excel will store it as a `1`. And yes you can, you just need a single additional instruction to assign the `.Range("A1").NumberFormat`, or change your assignment to be `= "'" & ws3.Cells(i, 1).Text`

Comment: Thanks,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,you saved the day..trying all different ways since 9am...I used the second method you suggested. Care to post something so I can give you some reward points?